# "response.json is not a function" Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object' angular8

Tags: angular

someone can tell me where is the problem.

code stresses on json.

```
 getPost(){
    this.postService.getAll()
     .subscribe(
       response=>{
       this.posts=response.json();
    },error=>{
      alert('error innattendue')
      console.log(error)
    }
    );
  }
```

Comment: `.json()` has been removed from Http since you import it from `@angular/common/http`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response should be json that you need, so if you directly use response it should work

```
 getPost(){
    this.postService.getAll()
     .subscribe(
       response=>{
       this.posts=response;
    },error=>{
      alert('error innattendue')
      console.log(error)
    }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this.posts=response;
Use like this. This will resolve your issue.